# Understanding Free monad in scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz, free-monad

I'm experimenting with `Free` monad in `Scalaz` and trying to build simple interpreter to parse and evaluate expressions like:

```
dec(inc(dec(dec(10)))
```

where `dec` means decrement, `inc` means increment. Here is what I got:

```
trait Interpreter[A]
case class V[A](a: A) extends Interpreter[A]

object Inc {
  private[this] final val pattern = Pattern.compile("^inc\\((.*)\\)$")
  def unapply(arg: String): Option[String] = {
    val m = pattern.matcher(arg)
    if(m.find()){
      Some(m.group(1))
    } else None
  }
}

object Dec {
  private[this] final val pattern = Pattern.compile("^dec\\((.*)\\)$")
  def unapply(arg: String): Option[String] = {
    val m = pattern.matcher(arg)
    if(m.find()){
      Some(m.group(1))
    } else None
  }
}

object Val {
  def unapply(arg: String): Option[Int] =
    if(arg.matches("^[0-9]+$")) Some(Integer.valueOf(arg))
    else None
}
```

Now this is all I need to build AST. It currently looks as follows:

```
def buildAst(expression: String): Free[Interpreter, Int] = 
   expression match {
     case Inc(arg) => inc(buildAst(arg))
     case Dec(arg) => dec(buildAst(arg))
     case Val(arg) => value(arg)
}

private def inc(i: Free[Interpreter, Int]) = i.map(_ + 1)
private def dec(d: Free[Interpreter, Int]) = d.map(_ - 1)
private def value(v: Int): Free[Interpreter, Int] = Free.liftF(V(v))
```

Now when testing the application:

```
object Test extends App{

  val expression = "inc(dec(inc(inc(inc(dec(10))))))"

  val naturalTransform = new (Interpreter ~> Id) {
    override def apply[A](fa: Interpreter[A]): Id[A] = fa match {
      case V(a) => a
    }
  }

  println(buildAst(expression).foldMap(naturalTransform)) //prints 12
}
```

And it works pretty much fine (I'm not sure about if it is in `scalaz` style).

***THE PROBLEM*** is the extractor objects `Inc`, `Dec`, `Val` feels like boilerplate code. Is there a way to reduce such a code duplication.

This will definitely become a problem if the number of functions supported  gets larger.

Comment: Parsing strings is not good use case for `Free`. It's meant to describe a number of operations that can be sequenced (DB calls, FS operations) without defining its implementation, allowing e.g. easy testing and switching between sync/async execution without changes to actual code

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov The thing is in my case `V` is not going to be the only one imlementation of `Interpreter`. There will be another one with side-effect (retreiving from database). That's why I thought it's a good idea to use `Free`.

Comment: The whole problem seems to be with top-down parsers rather than with `Free`. The `case class V[A](a: A)` is the *only* operation in your `Interpreter` trait that can be meaningfully replaced by different interpretations. Single operation that takes no inputs: that looks somehow like a rather incomplete embedded domain specific language?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Still a bit unclear about why isn't `Free` useful here. Can you please explain where is my understanding of the `Free` wrong? The thing is `case class V(a)` maybe interpreted as the number of row in the database. Therefore it's value is not known beforehand. So using `Free` maybe useful for testing (avoiding DB-related side-effects).

Comment: @St.Antario I didn't claim that `Free` isn't useful. I just pointed out that the question seems to be 95% top-down parsing and 5% about `Free`. The whole `pattern-compile-pattern-matching-group-match-case` stuff has nothing to do with `Free`, so `Free` is not the cause of boilerplate here. Furthermore, if `V(a)` is supposed to be interpreted as number of row that stores information of an object of type `A`, then `V` should be rather something `case class V[A](rowIdx: Int) extends Interpreter[A]`, because otherwise I don't get why you would want to pass in values of type `A` to get `A`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yes, I agree that parsing is not a good use case for that anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free monads are creating some boilerplate and that is a fact. However if you are willing to stick to some conventions, you could rewrite interpreter with [Freasy Monad](https://github.com/Thangiee/Freasy-Monad):

```
@free trait Interpreter {
  type InterpreterF[A] = Free[InterpreterADT, A]
  sealed trait InterpreterADT[A]


  def inc(arg: InterpreterF[Int]): InterpreterF[Int]
  def dec(arg: InterpreterF[Int]): InterpreterF[Int]
  def value(arg: Int): InterpreterF[Int]
}
```

and that would generate all of case classes and matching on them. The interpreter becomes just a trait to implement.

However, you already have some logic within unapply - so you would have to split the parsing and executing logic:

```
import Interpreter.ops._
val incP = """^inc\\((.*)\\)$""".r
val decP = """^dec\\((.*)\\)$""".r
val valP = """^val\\((.*)\\)$""".r
def buildAst(expression: String): InterpreterF[Int] = expression match {
  case incP(arg) => inc(buildAst(arg))
  case decP(arg) => dec(buildAst(arg))
  case valP(arg) => value(arg.toInt)
}
```

Then you could implement an actual interpreter:

```
val impureInterpreter = new Interpreter.Interp[Id] {
  def inc(arg: Int): Int = arg+1
  def dec(arg: Int): Int = arg-1
  def value(arg: Int): Int = arg
}
```

and run it:

```
impureInterpreter.run(buildAst(expression))
```

I admit that this is more of a pseudocode than tested working solution, but it should give a general idea. Another library that uses similar idea is [Freestyle](https://github.com/frees-io/freestyle) but they use their own free monads implementation instead of relying on a cats/scalaz.

So, I would say it is possible to remove some boilerplate as long as you have no issue with splitting parsing and interpretation. Of course not all can be removed - you have to declare possible operations on your `Interpreter` algebra as well as you have to implement interpreter yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the thing this is still unclear to me is when to use `Return` node and when to use `Suspend` node. Can you please clarigy it in a nutshell?

Comment: For me return and suspend are kind of leaky "implementation details", return is wrapping up already computer pure values, and suspend uses by-name parameter so that the Free value will be calculated lazily later on - this way you can avoid stack overflow during e.g. creating nested structure of arbitrary depth.